# v-binded image from local machine wont show, but from web does

Tags: vue.js

I want to change image dependent on variant of product selected, so I have to bind image property using v-bind.

When I put address of image on web in my variable it works, but when I put address of image from my PC (relative - using `../assets/image.jpeg`, or using `@/assets/image.jpeg`  or  absolute address - `/home/.../assets/image.jpeg`) it won't show. I don't get any error message.

This is problematic code:

```js
<template>
 <div class="product" v-for="(product, prodId) in products" :key="prodId">
  <!-- Element in question -->
  <img :src="product.variants[product.selectedVariant].url" alt="picture">
  <div v-for="(variant, variantId) in product.variants" :key="variantId"
    :class="variant.color"
     @mouseover="selectedVariant(prodId, variantId)"></div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name:'ProductSection',
    methods:{
        selectedVariant(prodId, variantId){
            this.products[prodId].selectedVariant= variantId
        }
    },
    data(){
        return {
            products: [{
                name: 'Billiard Balls',
                //Image address is value of url key
                variants: [{color: 'red', url: '@/assets/red.jpeg'}, {color: 'blue', url: '@/assets/blue.jpeg'}],
                selectedVariant: 0
            }, {
                name: 'Car Toy',
                variants: [{color: 'red', url: '@/assets/redCar.jpeg'}, {color: 'yellow', url: '../assets/YellowCar.jpeg'}],
                selectedVariant: 0
            }]
        }
       }
      } 
</script>
```

And side question is Where do my images end up when I build project? Do i have to deploy assets file along side built file?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't import image. I should have done

```
import image from '@/assets/image.jpeg'
```

and then

```
variants: [{color: 'red', url: image}, ...]
```